# Is there a way to tell whether a wordpress site is self-hosted or on wordpress.com?

Tags: wordpress, iframe, self-hosting

I can tell whether a site is using Wordpress by looking at the folder where the images are saved (usually site.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/image.jpg) or by looking at the source (if they are using plugins it will show).

But is there a way to tell whether a site is using wordpress.com or is self-hosted?

The reason I ask is that self-hosted WP sites allow iframes, while WP sites on wordpress.com don't.

Comment: Z suggestion: "make (the iframe configuration) a setting".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the DNS for the domain or IP with `whois`.

A site hosted at WordPress.com, even with a custom domain, will have an DNS records that point to NS1.WORDPRESS.COM, NS2.WORDPRESS.COM, NS3.WORDPRESS.COM

And in page source, images, etc, will be mapped to `s0.wp.com` or similar, or `accountname.files.wordpress.com` or similar, and not `domain.com/wp-content/uploads/...` as in self-hosted.

Comment: so anything on the dns records but the ones you list means it's self-hosted, correct?

great tip, thank you!